# How do I use javascript or jquery to find a sum and product of values from a forms field inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, jquery-calculation

How do I use javascript or jquery to find a sum and product of number values that users enter into my forms fields.  Thanks for your time and help.

Input 1 Value + Input 2 Value = Input A

Input A Value * .08 = Input B Value

Input A Value + Input B Value = Total Input

```
<form>

<input type="text" id="1" name="1">
<input type="hidden" id="2" name="2" value="33">
<input type="text" id="A" name="A">
<input type="text" id="B" name="B">
<input type="text" id="total" name="total">

<button type="button" id="button" name="button">

</form>
```

**WHAT IVE TRIED**

```
<script>

var $form = $('#contactForm'),
    $summands = $form.find('.sum1'),
    $sumDisplay = $('#itmttl');

$form.delegate('.sum1', 'change', function ()
{
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function ()
    {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });

    $sumDisplay.val(sum);
});

</script>

<script>

    function multiply(one, two) {
  if(one && two){
    this.form.elements.tax.value = one * two;
  } else {
    this.style.color='blue';
  }
}





</script>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: ive tried adding fields together but I cant get past that...

Comment: just post what you have tried..

Comment: ive been trying to figure this out for days now and I cant seem to get nowhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find Fiddle link

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s3hoeqw/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calculate').on('click',function(){
     var v1 =  $('#1').val();  // take first text box value
     var v2 =  $('#2').val();  // take second hidden text box value
     $('#A').val(parseInt(v1)+parseInt(v2)); // set value of A
     var aval = (parseInt($('#A').val()) * parseFloat(.8)); // calculate value of b
     $('#B').val(aval);// set value of B
     var totalval = parseInt($('#A').val()) + parseFloat(aval);
     //calculate value for total
     $("#total").val(totalval); // set total
  })

});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help it works good...but i notice when i change the value of input 2 to a decimal number like 1.11 it wont add decimal numbers...anyway to fix this?    http://jsfiddle.net/1s3hoeqw/2/

Comment: total value still not showing in 2 decimal number format

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to update the fields when you lick the button? Created a snippet instead of a fiddle:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#A").val( parseInt($("#1").val()) + parseInt($("#2").val()) );
  $("#B").val(parseInt($("#A").val()) * .8);
  $("#total").val( parseInt($("#A").val()) + parseInt($("#B").val()) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input type="text" id="1" name="1">
  <input type="hidden" id="2" name="2" value="33">
  <input type="text" id="A" name="A">
  <input type="text" id="B" name="B">
  <input type="text" id="total" name="total">

  <button type="button" id="button" name="button">

</form>
```

Comment: thanks...the button is not important i need this to work when the page loads and or when a user changes or enters a value